# Choosing between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1?

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8

- UTF-8 - Character encoding for Unicode
- ISO-8859-1 - Character encoding for the Latin alphabet

I'm not understanding both of these: where should I use this and in what cases on pages ?

Especially which one is suitable for login pages ?

Comment: This is too broad, and it is unclear what you are asking (this might relate to web pages, but the tags are very generic), and the question is probably mostly off-topic (a matter of choosing between character encodings).

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 0):

Both encoding schemes are widely used on internet.

In summary, UTF-8 supports a lot more characters (all characters in the [Unicode character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)).

There are many languages ISO-8859-1 does not support. For example, Chinese characters.

Read about [the languages ISO-8859-1 supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).